# How to save this question?

Tags: discussion

The following question [How to develop and optimize the illusion of meaningful character development between the player and NPCs? [on hold]](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/103547/how-to-develop-and-optimize-the-illusion-of-meaningful-character-development-bet) will be deleted in 24 hours.

I request some ideas on how I can shrink the scope of the question to make it on topic. I agree with DMGregory that the question is academic and their may not exist a simple recipe answer. I believe that this post will prove valuable for many developers down the road, because as Extra Credit has stated, this is a current issue that has high demand for advancement and implementation.

Comment: Take it to a discussion forum. Put a link in the comments of the question.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can.

The closest reasonable question I think you could extract from that would be along the lines of "I have a corpus of recorded dialog, I want to reuse that dialog as much as possible when writing new dialog, how can I mark up and/or track the recorded dialog and my new dialog to help me achieve this automatically?"

But I'm not sure that's what you're after, and in any case isn't necessarily a game-development specific question. Although it's certainly an interesting thing to thing about.

But I think you should take your question to an actual discussion forum. I think it will have a better chance of getting you the dialog (hah) that you want.